# Hello, I need to filter a list of contacts but NSPredicate don't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nspredicate

I need to filter a list of contacts, but not copy that after a certain amount of letters attached filter is damaged sample images and the `NSPredicate` I'm using.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"CAST(SELF.compositeName, 'NSString') contains[cd] %@",self.SearchNames.text];
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: English, please.  It's really hard to figure out what you're saying.

Comment: What does it means  " but not copy that after a certain amount of letters attached filter".

Comment: I'm using an array with Objects:   NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.compositeName, 'NSString') == %@",self.SearchNames.text];
        for(NSString *key in self.ContactsSectionTitles)
        {
            NSArray *result = [self.arrContacts objectForKey:key];
            
            
            
            NSArray *matches = [result filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
            
            if(matches.count > 1)
            {
            [self.FilteredNames addObject:matches];
            }
        }

Answer (score 1):

Your Predicate syntax is wrong.

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF.compositeName CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchText)
let filtredArray = NSArray(array: YourContactarray.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate))
```

When we work with array of dictionary then simply `SELF.key` is valid for predicate.

After this code reload your table with `filtredArray` which you can stored in another array for global access. Let me know if you have any problem in this code.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you have to filter the array using `NSPredicate`. You can follow the below link for filtering the array.

[NSPredicate Example](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/stevez/archive/2013/10/21/ios-objective-c-filtering-a-nsarray-using-nspredicate.aspx)

In that link, there are many examples for filtering array using using `NSPredicate`.

Here `array` means, which is used for displaying in `UITableView`.

Still you have questions, please post the code with array what you have used.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"compositeName CONTAINS[c] %@", searchText];
```